# wordpress underscore is loading after plugin that requires underscore

Tags: wordpress

I have a wordpress page that uses a plugin that requires underscore. I can see underscore loading after this ither plugin. how can I make sure the order is the correct one?

The error I get is

```
 Uncaught ReferenceError: _ is not defined at vc_grid.min.js?ver=5.7:1
```

If I copy the code of that file and execute it in the console after the page is loaded the pictures appear

You can try yourself here: https://www.hotelaldamagolf.com/hotel/

Comment: Is it a custom plugin that you developed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `defer` attribute when you register Underscore JS.

Because Underscore is loaded before VC Grid script but have `defer` attribute so it will executed after, at the end of page load (and after VC Grid also)